# Are there full scripts available for all episodes of season 2 of "Spider-Man Unlimited"?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

Just wanted to know if there is any site that has, or if the script writer has made public, the full scripts of all episodes of season 2 of *Spider-Man Unlimited* which got cancelled.

Comment: There's a synopsis here, but not scripts; https://tvwriter.com/animation/animation-spiderman-unlimited/spider-man-unlimited-second-season-arc/

Comment: Yeah i saw that when i was searching for it . I thought maybe there would be a full script somewhere , as the 13th episode ends with a climax